# Reading from an os.pipe() directly to a Tkinter text box

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pipe

I am trying to route the output of a separate script to a Tkinter window.

Below is my attempt at the problem. The Tkinter box appears but does not update when the controller (abstracted here) writes to pipeout using os.write(pipeout, msg) .

```
from Tkinter import *
from controller import controller
import os


def run():
"""Top level run method which initiates program."""

    def updateInput():
        """Update the textbox with controller output."""
        readFrom = os.fdopen(pipein)
        line = readFrom.readline()
        text.insert(END, line)
        text.after(1000, updateInput)


    pipein, pipeout = os.pipe() #pipe for comms between tkinter and controller
    pid = os.fork()
    if not pid:
        #within child process, launch controller with passed pipe
        os.close(pipein)
        mainController = controller(pipeout)
    os.close(pipeout)
    root = Tk()
    text = Text(root)
    text.pack()
    text.after(1000, updateInput) #update text box each second
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

The abstracted controller is writing to the pipe via

```
os.write(self.pipeout, msg)
```

where `self.pipeout` has been assigned from `self.pipeout = pipeout` in the controller class **init** .

Comment: What happens when `updateInput` runs? Does it crash? Does it read the wrong thing? Does it read OK but fails to insert the text? Where does the problem begin? It doesn't appear that you're actually writing anything.

Comment: It seems there is no read from the pipe. I'm using an os.write(self.pipeout, msg) statement at the other end to write into the pipe where self.pipeout is the assigned self.pipeout = pipeout . I'll update the question. @BryanOakley

Comment: What does "there is no read" mean? Is `updateInput` being called like you expect? Are you saying it's being called but is somehow skipping over the call to `read`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot to flush.

```
self.pipeout.write(msg)
self.pipeout.flush()
```

Also, make sure the msg ends in a newline.

Edit: are you sure you need a pipe? There's probably neater ways to do whatever you are doing, like threading.

Answer (score 0):

Solution came from using `os.read(pipein, 100)` instead of `os.fdopen(pipein)` in `updateInput`.

```
line = os.read(pipein, 100)
text.insert(END, line)
text.after(1000, updateInput)
```